# Proving an optimal solution to an LP also is optimal for a modified one

Tags: linear-programming

Consider the LP $\min cx $ subject to $a^i x = b_i $ $i=1,...,m$ and $x \geq0$ where $x$ is an n-vector. Let $x^*$ be an optimal solution to this LP. Let $\pi^*$ be the optimal solution to the dual. Prove that $x^*$ is also optimal to

\begin{align*}
\min \; \;& (c-\pi_k^* a^k) x \\
&a^i x = b_i, i=1,...,m \\
&x \geq 0 
\end{align*}

whre $\pi_k^*$ is kth component of the vector $\pi^*$

#### thoughts

We are given that $cx^* \leq cx $ for all $x$ feasible. By the duality theorem, we see that $\pi^* = x^*$. We need to prove that

$$  (c- \pi_k^* a^k ) x^* \leq (c- \pi_i^* a^i ) x $$

But, since $cx^* \leq cx$, then

$$ - \pi_k^* a^k x^* \leq - \pi_i^* a^i x \implies \pi_k^* a^k x^* \geq  \pi_i^* a^i x$$

here I get stuck. Am I thinking about this problem correctly? or my approach leads nowhere?

Comment: is it $x>0$ or $x \ge 0$?

Comment: yes, it is $x \geq 0$, i just updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new problem is $$\min (c^T-\pi_k^*e_k^TA)x$$

subject to $$Ax=b$$

$$x \ge 0$$

and the corresponding dual is

$$\max y^Tb$$

subject to $$y^TA \le (c^T-\pi_k^*e_k^TA)$$

At $x^*$ which is feasible in the primal, the optimal value is evaluated to be $$(c^T-\pi_k^*e_k^TA)x^*=b^T\pi^{*}-\pi_k^*e_k^Tb$$

Let's check if $y^*=\pi^*-\pi_k^*e_k$ is feasible for the new dual problem.

We have $$y^{*T}A = (\pi^*-\pi_k^*e_k)^TA  \le (c^T-\pi_k^*e_k^TA),$$

$y^*$ is indeed feasible and

$$y^{*T}b = (\pi^*-\pi_k^*e_k)^Tb$$

which is equal to the primal objective value evaluated at $x^*$. Hence by strong duality, $x^*$ remains optimal.

Comment: thanks for you reply. But, my approach is correct? Can you tell me if my attempted solution is correct? thanks

Comment: Statement of duality theorem is $\pi^{*T}b=c^Tx^*$. Also from $a \le b$ and $c \le d$, I don't think we can conclude that $(a-c) \le (b-d)$ .

Comment: The $y$ is unrestricted right? Also, can you explain why the second inequality starting from the end is true?

Comment: $y$ can take any sign. Also, since $\pi^*$ is feasible in the original dual, we ahve $\pi^{*T}A \le c^T$.

Comment: Why is 

$$(c^T-\pi_k^*e_k^TA)x^*=b^T\pi^{*}-\pi_k^*e_k^Tb$$

true? I understand $Ax^* = b $, but how $c x^* = b \pi^* $?

Comment: that is strong duality.

Comment: Why do you put the basis vector $e_k$? in the vector $c - \pi^*_k a^k $  , isnt the $a^k = (a_{k1},a_{k2},...,a_{kn})$?

Comment: It is more of a habit thing. if I see $Ax$ explicitly, I can subconsciously write down $b$ without thinking.

Comment: So, just the clarify then, the vector $c-\pi_k^*a^k $ is supposed to be the n-vector for which the jth component is given by $c_j- \pi^*_k a_{kj} $, correct?

Comment: yup, that's correct.